# Adding a "total sum" row with a select statement in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Query:

```
SELECT   (CASE
           WHEN a.account_number = '123456' THEN 'Savings'
           WHEN a.account_number = '123321' THEN 'Credit'
         END) AS "Account"
FROM accounts a
GROUP BY (CASE
           WHEN a.account_number = '123456' THEN 'Savings'
           WHEN a.account_number = '123321' THEN 'Credit'
         END);
```

Output:

```
+---------+
| Account |
+---------+
| Savings |
| Credit  |
+---------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+---------+
| Account |
+---------+
| Savings |
| Credit  |
| Total   |
+---------+
```

Given this query, how can I add a new row with the totals on the bottom?
Later I'm going to be doing more transactions...

Comment: Don't think it's the right approach. Can you rephrase your question a little more general (what goal you want to reach) and also add your table layout to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably Savings == Debit?

It might well be easier to do this in the programming language rather than the query, but could you try something like:

```
SELECT   IFNULL((CASE
           WHEN a.account_number = '123456' THEN 'Savings'
           WHEN a.account_number = '123321' THEN 'Credit'
         END), "Total") AS "Account"
FROM accounts a
GROUP BY a.account_number WITH ROLLUP;
```

I've not tried this yet so not 100% certain it will work, or how to make it named "Total" (it will be under `NULL`).

See [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name not sure how I missed the formatting, was about to edit it too!

Comment: Great idea @user3037661 for the Total, I didn't think of that!

Comment: Thank you. Had been searching for a while to find out what this feature was called again. Everyone everywhere was using variables for cumulatives.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your diagram is it a total row that you're after? I'm a little confused.

However, if it is a total row adding all credits and debits together then i would look into the UNION statement.

basic example:

```
SELECT a.AccountCreditsDebits From Table
UNION
SELECT SUM(a.AccountCreditsDebits) From Table
```